# Windows Key + [key] shortcut in Winforms App (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an application that runs in the sysetm tray, is it possible to allow users to restore the application via the Windows Key + *key* in C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using *Windows API*. I think that Windows Key is the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> but I'm not sure.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class InterceptKeys
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Comment: Windows key is the same as CTRL+ESC? Are you sure?

Comment: Not sure. I know that if you press Ctrl+Esc it has the same effect as the Windows key.

Comment: You're right David, is not the same. I've read it on Wikipedia but it's "capturable" any way. Mantorok, you should check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key becouse there're some combinations with the Windows key already reserved by the OS.

Comment: @Jamie "some combinations with the windows key already reserved by the OS" Did you read my answer?!! They are all reserved! Only some currently have actions associated with them, but they are **all reserved**.

Comment: @David Well maybe I didnt express myself very well. "I ment have actions associated with them". A combination of keys cannot be reserved.

Comment: @Jaime No, Windows reserves all keyboard shortcuts which use the Windows key for its own use. Apps are not supposed to use them. It also reserves a few others, e.g. CTRL+ESC, ALT+ESC, ALT+TAB etc.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can do this, you should not.  Shortcuts using the Windows key belong to Windows and should never be used by other application.

In fact, even global system wide shortcuts are a problem because they may well clash with another applications shortcuts.  This is the main reason Windows is able to use system wide shortcuts associated with the Windows key because the contract is that it reserves those shortcuts for its use and your app doesn't, thus avoiding clashes.

If you do decide to do this, and I ever run into your software, then I will hate you with a passion for as long as I live!

Comment: +1: Don't know who down voted this: don't shoot the messenger just because you don't like the message.

Comment: @Richard Indeed! And thanks. I was expecting some down votes, but I'm also fairly sure that the majority of right minded people on Stack Overflow will recognise the value in what I say!

Comment: @Jaime I din't vote you down but I disagree when you say that "Windows key belongs to Windows", Windows key belongs to me becouse I'm the owner of the full keyboard and the computer where it's connected.

Comment: @Jaime Read again. I didn't say "Windows key belongs to Windows", I said "Shortcuts using the Windows key belong to Windows".

Comment: @David First line: "Windows key belongs to Windows". Here is a full sample Hooking the windows key: http://codeidol.com/csharp/csharpckbk2/Delegates,-Events,-and-Anonymous-Methods/Using-the-Windows-Keyboard-Hook/

Comment: @Jaime It says "Shortcuts using the Windows key belong to Windows". The noun which belongs to Windows is "Shortcuts" rather than "key".

Comment: @David You're right you didn't say the Key but the Shortcuts using it.

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying, this particular application is actually just a personal application.  I currently use Executor: http://executor.dk/ and very much like ability to assign any shortcut to bring up the window.

Comment: @Manotork That's fine and clearly for a personal app it's OK. But this answer can stay here as a reminder to anyone who stumbles upon this question who is thinking of distributing their app!!

Comment: @Mantok check this http://codeidol.com/csharp/csharpckbk2/Delegates,-Events,-and-Anonymous-Methods/Using-the-Windows-Keyboard-Hook/

Comment: @Jamie: You're missing the point. No one is saying "it is not possible". We're saying (as MS does) all Windows key based shortcuts are reserved for Windows itself: ["All Windows key combinations, whether currently assigned or not, are reserved for definition by the system only"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997427.aspx).

Comment: @David Ok but Manotork wanted to do it anyway so I'm telling him how to do it. I hope it's Ok...

Comment: @Jaime That's fine, at least he and you are aware that this is technically breaking the rules.

Comment: @Jaime You're welcome ;-) Anyway, you picked up 45 rep, and I'm only +8. It just goes to show that crime does pay!